# np.pad() function eating RAM

Tags: python, numpy

whenever I try to add padding to my image it eats my memory even though the images are fairly small. 3.09 MB and 8.51 KB and using the function eats 20 GB of my ran and all 8 GB of my swap space

```
chest = cv2.imread(resource_path("chest.png"))
speed = cv2.imread(resource_path("7.png"))

speed_height = speed.shape[0]
chest_height = chest.shape[0]

combine = np.pad(chest,((speed_height - cest_height,0)))
```

Comment: The file sizes may be small, but what are the dimensions?

Comment: 3129,2838 and 30,40 respectivley

Comment: Does it give you an error message?  If so, what array shape is it trying to create.  Is `chest` (30,40) or (30,40,3)?  `dtype`?  `np.pad` is complex because of its generality.  It may be better to create a `combine` of the desired end shape, and copying `chest` to it with the right `slice` indexing.

Comment: How about creating an empty array with np.zeros from there you pad in the shape with slicing as such new_array[:10, :] = [0, 1]

Comment: I suspect it's trying to create a `combine` with shape `(3129, 3139, 3102)`

Comment: @hpaulj it gives no error message, it just eats RAM and freezes my computer if I let it run for more than a few seconds, chest is (30, 40, 3) and the other is (3129, 2838, 3), dtype for both is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: reread the pad dimensions docs

Comment: @hpaulj ```pad_width{sequence, array_like, int}
Number of values padded to the edges of each axis. ((before_1, after_1), … (before_N, after_N)) ``` I want to pad speed_height - chest_height on the first axis (vertical) I don't see what im doing  wrong

Comment: @hpaulj ok i disabled my swap partition and tried it again and it gave me a memory error this time ```MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (3129, 3139, 3102) and data type uint8
``` i don't know what its trying to make such a large array

Comment: It's trying to pad all 3 dimensions by the same amount.  The pad amount spec is wrong.